# What to do with old answers flagged as Low Quality on old questions that should be closed?

Tags: discussion

Regarding this review:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9969317

The first answer on that question popped up in the VLQ yesterday. I immediately noticed that the question itself was **7 years old** and poor by current SO standards, so I went and cast a close vote **on the question** and skipped the VLQ answer. Because, after all, what's the point on voting to delete a bad answer on a bad question that's going to be closed anyway?

Today I was perusing the VLQ and one of the other answers on that same question popped up. Again, I voted to skip for the same reason as above.

So my question is twofold:

1. Is flagging low-quality answers on ancient, bad questions encouraged or discouraged?
2. If the latter, should there be some sort of mechanism in place to warn users "hey, you're flagging a REALLY OLD answer, are you sure you shouldn't be flagging the question instead?".

This is somewhat of an edge case, but it seems to have become less of an edge case lately going on what I've seen in the VLQ, hence this question.

Comment: Good news is now it's a closed question with no accepted or positively scored answers, and I assume no reopen votes, the roomba [should delete it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/305827) in a few days.

Comment: Posting time doesn't matter, IMO. Up/down vote as appropriate and flag as well, if needed.

Answer (score 7):

If the answer is bad, downvote / flag the answer.
If the question is bad, downvote / flag the question.

Act on the answer based on the answer itself. Not on the question it's posted on.

If the question is bad, and the answer should be deleted, flag / vote on both the question and the answer.

> *"Is flagging low-quality answers on ancient, bad questions encouraged or discouraged?"*

There's nothing wrong with flagging / downvoting obsolete answers that are *incorrect* or very low quality, such as link-only answers. (Especially if the links have been broken).

> If the latter, should there be some sort of mechanism in place to warn users "hey, you're flagging a REALLY OLD answer, are you sure you shouldn't be flagging the question instead?".

Nope, flag both.

Comment: *"If the question is bad, and the answer should be deleted, flag / vote on both the question and the answer."* No. Take for example a recommendation request as a question. "What library can I use to foo the bar?" and the answer is no more than "libbaz1337", then it *answers* the question however bad that question is. It's not low-quality, because how can it be low-quality if it fully answers the question? The question is the problem and should be closed. I would probably click *Looks ok* in this case go to the question and vote to close it.

Comment: A bad answer doesn't _"Look OK"_, though. Answer like that _should_ at very least be downvoted, but preferably be flagged / delete-voted too.

Comment: Downvoting is fine if it's a few of many answers of a single question, if all of the answers are "bad", then the question should be closed instead of going on a downvoting rampage. If the answers are fresh, then they probably should receive a comment saying that answering bad questions doesn't help the site in any way.

Comment: "how can it be low-quality if it fully answers the question?" I will go ahead and argue that a full answer to a question *that should not be asked* is *inherently* low quality. Whether that's a library recommendation, or a code dump in response to a request for a code dump.

Answer (score 2):

I've got rep to burn here.

It seems to me that if the low quality of the answer is similar to the low quality of the question, it is reasonable to leave it until the question gets swatted. A no-effort question deserves a no-effort answer.

Comment: I dissent: a no-effort question deserves *no* answer, and answers are in fact counterproductive to the site's goals.